# Windows API functions

Tags: windows, winapi

Are they standard code c or c++ code? what are they?

Comment: Is this purely for intellectual curiosity, or do you have a more specific question in mind? If so, we might be able to give better answers if you provide some more context to your question.

Comment: This is an odd question. As Cody says you might get better answers if you explained the motivation behind the question. Essentially though you do not need to know. The Windows API is an opaque interface. You just call it and don't worry about what's on the other side of the interface. You just need to know what it does, not how it does it.

Comment: Hi, just when I heard the word 'sleep' is not a standard function I got it confused with captial 'S' 'Sleep'. On my compiler 'sleep' is unknown function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original Win32 API is C-based.  There are however a substantial number of services within Windows that are COM based.  Good examples are the clipboard, drag+drop, the shell, the user mode driver framework, DirectX.  While it is technically possible to write COM code in C, it is excruciatingly painful to do so.

Realistically you use C++ there.  And a C++ class library to make the original C-based API less painful, especially for GUI code.

Comment: The clipboard and D&D also have older C interfaces (But they lack some of the features like multiple format support for the clipboard etc)

Answer (score 2):

They're standard C code, if you're programming against pure Windows API.

A C++ based wrapper called [MFC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Foundation_Class_Library) is available.

All of this is being pushed out in favor of [.NET framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework).

Comment: +1 Although I have to say, I chuckle at the irony of claiming the Windows API is being phased out in favor of the .NET Framework. A lot of the .NET Framework is just a wrapper for that same API implemented in managed code. It's not dead quite yet!

Answer (score 0):

The standard Windows API is a C library. Wrappers exist for other languages (C++, etc).

Just read it on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API).

Answer (score 0):

Windows API is langugage neutral. It is neither C nor C++. Microsoft says that Windows itself is written mainly in C++, but you don't need any classes for vast majority of the API and even classes in API (e.g. in Direct X) can be used in pure C without classes.

Although some C programmers think it is a C library, compiler of a programming language must support proprietary Windows calling model, it is not a classic C calling convention. (Obviously almost each real world C compiler supports it nowadays.)

Comment: The fact that the Windows API uses `__stdcall` doesn't disqualify it from being a C library. There are several popular calling conventions in use, even among C compilers (or, at least, there *were*; things have a way of changing a lot in 20 years). You're right that it's language neutral in the sense that it can be *consumed* from any language, but pure, bare-metal Windows API programming is straight C, albeit with a few Microsoft-specific extensions.

Comment: "Microsoft says that Windows itself is written mainly in C++" I'd like a citation please, because I'm quite confident that statement is false and MS never said so.

Comment: @David: Several web sites cite Bill gates that Windows is written mainly in C++. But I never saw the source, so it may be some sort of hoax.

Comment: @Al Kepp: http://web.archive.org/web/20040213062752/http://heim.ifi.uio.no/~mortehu/files.txt shows that back in 2000, it was 90% c, with some c++ in IE/Trident and Explorer/Shell32 (That is not the complete tree, not sure how much of the source actually leaked)

Comment: @Al @Anders Indeed so! Any C++ in Windows is most likely to be found in the outer layers. Here's betting that the kernel has no C++ and is entirely C/assembly.